# How can I get a clean URL from a href selector with Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

When I inspect the source code on the results page of a Google search, I see the URL I'm looking for. Something like this:

```html
<a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/<product_name>/dp/<product_code>" ping=...> </a>
```

But when I use Scrapy to retrieve that same URL with the following selector:

```py
response.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'amazon.com')]/@href").get()
```

I get the following URL that doesn't work:

```py
'/url?q=https://www.amazon.com/<product_name>/dp/<product_code>&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjbjbqFzPLsAhWQpFkKHUgfA50QFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0cZpoBVRm94Z7lbphHTjsW'
```

Considering I don't want to slice the strings manually:

1. How can I get the URL without the `/url?q=`at the very beginning?
2. And how can I get the URL without the last piece of random stuff?

Comment: Use [w3lib.url.url_query_parameter](https://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.url.url_query_parameter)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `/url?q=` part from the string:

```
url = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'amazon.com')]/@href").get().replace('/url?q=','').split('&')[0]
```

Or if strictly at beginning use Regex:

```
import re
url = re.sub('^\/url\?q\=','',response.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'amazon.com')]/@href").get()).split('&')[0]
```

Comment: plus: `url.split("&")[0]` to remove that "random stuff" aka query string as in requirement #2